# $a^2=ab+b^2+b+5$ has no integer solutions

Tags: number-theory

Prove that the equation $a^2=ab+b^2+b+5$ has no integer solutions.

My attempt:

$4a^2=4ab+4b^2+4b+20$

$4a^2-4ab+b^2 = 5b^2+4b+20$

$5(4a^2-4ab+b^2) = 5(5b^2+4b+20)$

$5(2a-b)^2=(5b+2)^2+96$

Let $2a-b = x$, $\;5b+2=y$

we get $\;5x^2-y^2=96$.

Please suggest on how to proceed.

Comment: have you though about what parity a and b must be ? if so you'd limit your checks a lot.

Comment: You can test directly that $a^2=ab+b^2+b+5$ has no solution mod $9$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$5x^2-y^2 = 84 \implies 2x^2-y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$$
which implies $3\mid x$ and $3\mid y$. But $9\nmid 84$.

---

Your original equation should be equivalent to $$5x^2-y^2 = 96$$
where $x=2a-b, y=5b+2$. But the above method works fine for $96$ too.

Comment: in the comments i was more going towards if a is even then b being either odd or even doesn't work out, if a is odd only b being even works out.

Comment: I got it now. Thank you all :)

Comment: `\implies` $\implies$ and `\iff` $\iff$ are good commands for in the future.